# Hide back button in tabbar navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I need to hide the `Back` that is overlapping with `Cart`

[image]

**Edit 1**
I have already added these things

```
   override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.title = "Orders"
      //  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Cart", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Cart", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Cart", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.title = "Orders"
        self.navigationItem.title = "Order History"
     //   self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Cart", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Cart", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
         self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Cart", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this place

```
 self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```

try this

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: UIView())
```

**option-2**

```
 self.tabbarcontroller.navigationcontroller.navigationitem.hidesBackButton = true
self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Cart", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title:"Cart", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: nil)
```

Comment: It didnot help either

Comment: @onkar - try with option-2 answer

Answer (score 0):

```
self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, write this code on view controller which appear after 1st navigationcontroller ( PushViewController ).

```
self.navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 self.tabBarController!.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
```